# Does having multiple instances of a class (Reference Type) make it thread safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, castle-windsor

Hoping you can help me clear up my understanding on thread safety and multiple instances of a reference type.

I've outlined a simple scenario below. My question is: if ProcessorOne and ProcessorTwo are running at the same time, and if the DatabaseIntegration class is a reference type and ProcessorOne and ProcessorTwo both have their own instances of DataBaseIntegration, then is the potential for the Entity saved by ProcessorOne to have the name from ProcessorTwo prevented?

```
public class ProcessorOne
{
    private readonly DatabaseIntegration databaseIntegration;
    public ProcessorOne(DatabaseIntegration databaseIntegration)
    {
        this.databaseIntegration = databaseIntegration;
    }

    public void Process()
    {                                  
       this.databaseIntegration.SetName("NameOne")
       Entity entity = new Entity()
       this.dataBaseIntegration.Save(entity);
    }
}

public class ProcessorTwo
{
    private readonly DatabaseIntegration dataBaseIntegration;
    public ProcessorTwo(DatabaseIntegration dataBaseIntegration)
    {
        this.dataBaseIntegration = dataBaseIntegration;
    }

    public void Process()
    {            
       this.databaseIntegration.SetName("NameTwo")
       Entity entity = new Entity()
       this.dataBaseIntegration.Save(entity);
    }
}

public class DatabaseIntegration 
{
    private string entityName;

    public void SetName(string entityName)
    {
        this.entityName = entityName;
    }

    public void Save(Entity entity)
    {            
         entity.EntityName = this.entityName;
         using (DbContext context = new DbContext(sqlConnection))
         {
             context.Entity.Add(entity);
             context.SaveChanges();                 
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thread-safety would require that data that is (potentially) shared between threads is accessed in a thread-safe manner (i.e., safe from race conditions). So, your question could be rather simplified: Are any methods of any instances (or static methods) which are called on different threads potentially accessing data that can potentially be accessed from some (other or same) method (irregardless of whether the method is from the same or a different class)?

Comment: Your code is thread safe yes. But you doesnot need 2 class, you can new this class tiwce, the code inside is thread safe. You have to take care to static data, files, thread waiting each other (deadlock), session...Here you only add a small lane in db with diffrerent connection/ transaction, the only thing what could occur, is a really lillte lock (few ms) on db side that s all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is yes they are thread safe. But why don't you set entity name as you create them. In that case even if you use the same DatabaseIntegration object it will still be thread safe because you pass different entity objects each time you call Save().

```
public class ProcessorOne
{
   private readonly DatabaseIntegration databaseIntegration;
   public ProcessorOne(DatabaseIntegration databaseIntegration)
   {
       this.databaseIntegration = databaseIntegration;
   }

   public void Process()
   {                                  
      Entity entity = new Entity(){entityName = "NameOne"}
      this.dataBaseIntegration.Save(entity);
   }
 }

public class ProcessorTwo
{
   private readonly DatabaseIntegration dataBaseIntegration;
   public ProcessorTwo(DatabaseIntegration dataBaseIntegration)
   {
       this.dataBaseIntegration = dataBaseIntegration;
   }

   public void Process()
   {            
      Entity entity = new Entity(){entityName = "NameTwo"}
      this.dataBaseIntegration.Save(entity);
   }
}

public class DatabaseIntegration 
{
   public void Save(Entity entity)
   {            
     using (DbContext context = new DbContext(sqlConnection))
     {
         context.Entity.Add(entity);
         context.SaveChanges();                 
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The example was intentionally poorly coded to help demonstrate a scenario where thread safety was an issue and could be mitigated by having multiple instances of the reference type class.

Answer (score 2):

No, they will have different names because, as you said, in your code each class has a difference instance of DatabaseIntegration.

So ProcessorOne will have the dataBaseIntegration name as "NameOne" and ProcessorTwo will have the dataBaseIntegration name as "NameTwo".

Regards.